# File Upload using Reactjs and Yii2 Api

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, yii2

I have spent the whole day trying to get a good files( Images and might be audios) uploader using reactjs frontend and storing the files in the backend using Yii2 API( PHP). Any recommendations or ideas around this task will be highly appreciated.

thanks

Comment: In react side  you can use`Uppy File Uploader` :  https://uppy.io/docs/react/ and in  yii2 just create a normal file upload api to accept the file as a form data and then save it to the server and return the url

Comment: @JoelJoseph Thanks for this. I will go through it .